IOS: Why doesn't the native Face ID alert show more than once?
Can anyone clarify (with a source) why when a user attempts to enable Face ID for an app, they only see the native alert prompt to activate it, if it's the first time they try to enable it?
Why do they have to manually go to the settings if they want to enable/re-enable it later?

It's the same for most permission requests in iOS. The app gets to ask once and the user answers.  If the user changes their mind then they can take action but the app can't pester the user with repeated requests

@Paulw11 This makes sense to me and I've seen this answer on 3 different sites now. But is there a source on it?

See Reset authorisation access
